# Can i set to true Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS from code?

Tags: android

I am curious if it's possible to preset the "Unknown Sources" to true in Android from code?
Can it be possible with a non-rooted device?

```
Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS, 1);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`INSTALL_NON_MARKET_APPS` is a Settings.Secure, and

> Secure system settings, containing system preferences that applications can read but are not allowed to write. These are for preferences that the user must explicitly modify through the system UI or specialized APIs for those values, not modified directly by applications.

So, no.

Please note that, as of API 17, this Setting is now part of Settings.Global. It does not change the access policy:

> Applications can read these but are not allowed to write; like the "Secure" settings, these are for preferences that the user must explicitly modify through the system UI or specialized APIs for those values.

Comment: Don't forget to accept and upvote by using the checkmark left of the answer and the arrow up.